# CUDA threads for inner loop

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu, nvidia

I've got this kernel

```
__global__ void kernel1(int keep, int include, int width, int* d_Xco, 
              int* d_Xnum, bool* d_Xvalid, float* d_Xblas)
{

  int i, k;  
  i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

  if(i < keep){

    for(k = 0; k < include ; k++){

      int val = (d_Xblas[i*include + k] >= 1e5);
      int aux = d_Xnum[i];

      d_Xblas[i*include + k] *= (!val);
      d_Xco[i*width + aux] = k;
      d_Xnum[i] +=val;
      d_Xvalid[i*include + k] = (!val);
    }
  }
}
```

launched with

```
int keep = 9000;
int include = 23000;
int width = 0.2*include;

int threads = 192;
int blocks = keep+threads-1/threads;
kernel1 <<< blocks,threads  >>>( keep, include, width,
                                 d_Xco, d_Xnum, d_Xvalid, d_Xblas );
```

This `kernel1` works fine but it is obviously not totally optimized. I thought it would be straight forward to eliminate the inner loop `k` but for some reason it doesn't work fine.
My first idea was:

```
__global__ void kernel2(int keep, int include, int width, 
               int* d_Xco, int* d_Xnum, bool* d_Xvalid, 
               float* d_Xblas)
{

  int i, k;  
  i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
  k = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;

  if((i < keep)  && (k < include) ) {

      int val = (d_Xblas[i*include + k] >= 1e5);
      int aux = d_Xnum[i];
      d_Xblas[i*include + k] *= (float)(!val);
      d_Xco[i*width + aux] = k;
      atomicAdd(&d_Xnum[i], val);
      d_Xvalid[i*include + k] = (!val);
  }
}
```

launched with a 2D grid:

```
int keep = 9000;
int include = 23000;
int width = 0.2*include;

int th = 32;
dim3 threads(th,th);
dim3 blocks ((keep+threads.x-1)/threads.x, (include+threads.y-1)/threads.y);
kernel2 <<< blocks,threads >>>( keep, include, width, d_Xco, d_Xnum, 
                               d_Xvalid, d_Xblas );
```

Although I believe the idea is fine, it does not work and I am running out of ideas here. Could you please help me out here? I also think the problem could be in `d_Xco` which stores the position `k` in a smaller array and push them to the beginning of the array , so the order matters.

```
d_Xco
-------------------------------
| 2|3 |15 |4 |5 |5 | | | | | | .......
-------------------------------
```

Comment: the grid should be created as `dim3 blocks((keep + threads.x -1)/threads.x,(include + threads.y - 1)/threads.y);`. You are forgetting brackets.

Comment: @ sgar91 sorry, it was a typo. Updated

Comment: Why does kernel2 does not work? It gives wrong results? It does not execute at all?

Comment: @pQB yeah, wrong results. It really speeds up, but...Execution is fine, fast and smooth.

Comment: And how are your data arrange? According to kernel2 you have `keep` columns and `include` rows.

Comment: @pQB: No, `keep` rows and `include` columns. But `d_Xco` supposes to store data depending on `aux` which is in essence a counter, so data should be stored consecutively. That works fine sequentially but when multiple threads are working at once, they might be storing data in `d_Xco` in a different order.

Answer (score 1):

In the original code, you have

```
for(k = 0; k < include ; k++){
  ...
  int aux = d_Xnum[i];
  ...
  d_Xco[i*width + aux] = k;
  ...
}
```

The index to the `d_Xco` array is not dependent on `k` and therefore writing to it each iteration is redundant. The final value will always be `include-1`. So, replace these two lines inside the `k` loop with one line *outside* the `k` loop:

```
 d_Xco[i*width + d_Xnum[i]] = include - 1;
```

Once you do that, when you parallelize the `k` loop you will no longer have the race condition you currently have when many `k` threads assign different values to the same location in `d_Xco` concurrently (no guarantee of ordering).

Comment: @ harrism: I do need the data of `d_Xco`, not only the last element.

Comment: @Manolete, in your sequential version, only the last element will remain! Step through the code in the debugger and see.